# Should I change the "etc_t" SELinux context for a custom application?

Tags: selinux

I'm using SELinux (targeted mode) to confine a custom application . I used the command `sepolicy generate --init` to automatically generate the contexts and rules, and everything went surprisingly well: all the resources are tagged with custom contexts, the applications works well.

However, I'm surprised that the configuration files under `/etc/customApplication` are still tagged with the `etc_t` context.

Is there a reason why `sepolicy generate --init` doesn't create a new `etc_t_customApplication` context for these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`etc_t` is an SELinux type applied by default as part of an SELinux context to files under /etc which are world-readable but owned and modifiable by root only* - @fpmurphy

In case you need to modify these configuration files using other applications/deamons or you need to hide these files from everything else you may indeed need your own context.

Comment: Perhaps the first sentence  should be modified to: `etc_t`  is an SELinux type applied by default as part of an SELinux context to files under /etc which are world-readable but owned and modifiable by root only.